# How to read values from txt file as Bytes using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, file, byte, txt

actually I want to read values from .txt file and send them to a card stm32 via bluetooth with Byte format.
I tried this solution but the values wasn't sent correctly.
And I got this exception : **type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List'**

This is the code:

```
  localPath() async {
    String textasset = "assets/112936-bluetooth.txt";
    String text = await rootBundle.loadString(textasset);
    print(int.parse(text));
    return int.parse(text);
  }
```

Here's where I call the function:

```
     onWritePressed: () {
                      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        c.write(localPath(), withoutResponse: true);
                    },
```

this is an example for some values in the .txt file:
**0x00, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x03, 0x2F, 0x2F, 0xCC, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x2A**
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `Future` instead of list to a method `write`. So change your code like this

```
onWritePressed: () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        localPath().then((val) => c.write(val, withoutResponse: true));
    }
},
```

For more info on Future, head to [future.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `localPath` function is returning a Future because it is async. You need to wait for it to resolve. Also, as written that Future will resolve to an `int`, not `List<int>`, so that needs to be fixed as well.

```dart
Future<List<int>> localPath() async {
  final textasset = "assets/112936-bluetooth.txt";
  final text = await rootBundle.loadString(textasset);
  final bytes = text //
    .split(',')
    .map((s) => s.trim())
    .map((s) => int.parse(s))
    .toList();
  print(bytes);
  return bytes;
}
```

Then in your handler:

```dart
onWritePressed: () async {
  final bytes = await localPath();
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    c.write(bytes, withoutResponse: true);
  }
},
```